What is the path where the data sent to a swagger api is stored. Where is it configured?
What is the path where the data sent to a swagger api is stored. Where is it configured?
I have created an api with swagger-editor, I generate the server in nodejs and put it on my server. I configure it to use port 8499 instead of 80 and disable CORS to be able to communicate with itself.
Accedoo to the web 127.0.0.1:4899/docs and this the swagger-ui, from there if I make the test of recovering with the examples, it works.
Now, I create a JSON object, it returns an OK, and says that the route will go in the response section of the headers.
These are my headers
 connection: keep-alive 
 content-type: application/json 
 date: Mon, 13 May 2024 11:41:42 GMT 
 keep-alive: timeout=5 
 transfer-encoding: chunked 
 x-powered-by: Express 

And this is the response
{
  "status": "201",
  "description": "The resource was created. The Response Location HTTP header should be returned to indicate where the newly created resource is accessible.",
  "more_info": ""
} 

The question is, where is this object, can I configure where it is stored so that I can retrieve it later?
added this parameters to the app.js to try if the persistence should be activated
// swaggerRouter configuration
var options = {
    routing: {
        controllers: path.join(__dirname, './controllers'),
**        cors:false,
        tryItOutEnabled:true,
        persistAuthorization:true**
    },


"I generate the server in nodejs" – you'll need to look at the generated code to see what it does.

I did it, but i 'm not used to nodejs, and didn't find anything. Could you give me an advice on what files should check o where to find information about this?

No, because I also don't know what files you have in the first place.

OpenAPI-based server generators typically generate a stub, that is, method declarations without actual business logic. Developers are then supposed to implement the necessary business logic, DB connections, etc. themselves. As @AKX said, you need to look at the generated code to see what it does (or does not do).

Damn! i was hoping swagger creates all the CRUD, and only have to configure the database or filespace for the JSON, to test it. Thanks for yours answers.
